# Using SAPI is there a way to dictate Chinese name and get pinyin or words just record the pronunciation?

Tags: c#, text-to-speech, sapi

The goal is to use SAPI to dictate Chinese name, and get pinyin or just words with same pronunciation to record the name's pronunciation. But when using DictationGrammar like below,

```
var engine = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
engine.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
var dictationGrammar = new DictationGrammar();
engine.LoadGrammar(dictationGrammar);
```

The result is always trying to get some meaningful phrases when dictate some Chinese names.

Is there a way to reach my goal? Thank you.

Comment: You need to provide some more details.   In particular, what is CultureInfo.CurrentCulture?

Comment: Also, are you willing to switch to C++?  The native API has a lot more functionality that isn't exposed in the managed wrappers, some of which is going to be needed to do what you want.

Comment: @Eric, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture is Chinese, more specifically, "zh-CN". C++ could be an option, although the whole architecture is C#, I could wrap some c++ dll to use.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using Dictation Grammar create your own grammar using ***Grammar builder()***-function and use it with ***Load grammar()***-function because dictation grammar is only for English words. even though using your own grammar but your accent should be US accent.

```
Choices sList = new Choices(); 
sList.Add(new string[] { "pinyin" });
Grammar gr = new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(sList));
engine.LoadGrammar(slist);
```

hope this will help you!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the pronunciation grammar.

```
var engine = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
engine.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
var dictationGrammar = new DictationGrammar("Pronunciation");
engine.LoadGrammar(dictationGrammar);
```

This will return a set of phonemes in the [Chinese phoneme set](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee125160(v=vs.85).aspx), and won't attempt to map that into a string.

Comment: I have tried this, but it doesn't work. Actually, using pronunciation grammer is still trying to recognize some meaningful string first, and then have a phoneme set from that string, rather than get directly from the audio. So this is not working well for people's names.

Comment: @ManShen Can you expand on that?   I'm not that familiar with the Chinese engine, but the English engine doesn't work that way; if you have the pronunciation model (and nothing else) loaded, it returns raw phonemes.